# Tag merge / synonym request: [dry] → [dry-principle]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [dry](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry) (27 questions) into [dry-principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry-principle) (5), and make them synonyms.

Preference for master tag is because I consider *dry-principle* a more descriptive name.

---

Tag *dry* wiki excerpt is

> DRY is short for "Don’t Repeat Yourself". This paradigm advocates to avoid code and data redundancy.

Tag *dry-principle* wiki excerpt is

> Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). Also known as Duplication Is Evil (DIE). The objective of DRY is to write code that is non-repetitive.

Comment: The fact that there are 27 questions for [tag:dry] and only 5 for [tag:dry-principle] might support the argument that [tag:dry] is more intuitively obvious, even if [tag:dry-principle] is technically more correct.

Comment: @DanPichelman well I merely explained my preference. Your reasoning makes pretty good sense though, so wouldn't mind _dry_ to be a master

Comment: update: it looks like [meta-tag:status-completed] now - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/dry/synonyms "...The following tags will be remapped to dry - dry-principle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done - according to [dry tag synonyms page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/dry/synonyms),

> The following tags will be remapped to [dry](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry)
>   [dry-principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry-principle)

---

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whFQB.png]